# Remove data on Firebase realtime database with firebase-admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I had succeeded to insert data on Firebase realtime database thanks to REST API but I did not to delete.

My data tree is:

```
PAPP : 10

PAPP_5MIN : 0

PAPPs/-KhPrX7MBbEYOZNCeSJ6 = {PAPP: 250, timestamp: 1491878158871}
PAPPs/-KhpRylKUC6MzJJSsjUG = {PAPP: 200, timestamp: 1492324183125}
PAPPs/-KhPs26RaSuQ972L1n07 = {PAPP: 180, timestamp: 1491878293980}
... (about 51 000 entries)
```

I have the Firebase Admin Microsoft Windows software and I need to execute a query to delete all PAPPs entries or better delete all entries older than 15 minutes.

Actually, the sample code that I can execute is:

```
firebase().database().ref('/PAPPs').on('value', function (snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

This give me all my 51 000 records.

How can I update this JS to delete my entries?

Comment: there is a function remove() (for more info see the doc. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write )

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative way using REST API DELETE Method

```
curl -X DELETE https://[MYPROJECT].firebaseio.com/PAPPs.json?auth=[SERVICE_ID]
```

Now I have to wait next month for quota reset to try more selective option with JS.
Any suggestion are welcome.